# VBC.exe to build standalone dlls in "newer" .net frameworks. (4.6 specifically)

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-4.6, vbc

I am working on upgrading an older "compiler" we have, which basically converts a spreadsheet into a .vb file, and then compiles it into a .net library.

It uses vbc.exe to compile the .vb file. Right now it seems the latest version of dll I can create is going to be in .net 4.0. the vbc file resides here `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.xxxx`. I know I have at least .net 4.6 installed, but i don't see a new directory for that. So I'm clearly oversimplifying this it seems.

I think I read the vbc.exe is more or less turning legacy and only exists to support older applications? Is there a new way to build standalone dlls like we could using vbc.exe to compile in the latest .net versions?

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/#installation-instructions---visual-studio-installer

Comment: I figured out how to get the Roslyn VBC.EXE, but It is still automatically compiling to .net 4.0. I have several versions of .net I can build to when I use visual studio, so i'm wondering why roslyn's vbc.exe is defaulting to .net 4.0?